# unable add case condition inside a where clause in oracle

Tags: oracle, case, where-clause

I have a procedure where I intialize the variable `i:=0` and I increment every time a loop runs. I need where should return one condition when `i:=0` and other when `i>0`

Query I wrote

```
Select ID from table 
where
case when i=0
then time <=end_time
when i>0
then time>start_time and time <=end_time
```

Could exactly get what should be done.

Comment: I believe case statement should give a result as a expression OR in other terms the result of your case statement should be compared with something instead being a  condition itself.

Comment: @RamaSh yes whole issue is how can I include this in where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of using case statement for this scenario you can rewrite your query as below:-

```
Select ID from table 
where (i=0 and time <=end_time)
   or (i>0 and (time>start_time and time <=end_time));
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to or statement:

```
 Select ID from table 
 where time <=end_time
 And (i<=0 or time>start_time)
```